# Cannot find the class DemoDragHandler in the gwt-dnd API

Tags: api, gwt

Can I get the link for the gwt API which contains the class `com.allen_sauer.gwt.dnd.demo.client.DemoDragHandler`?

I searched everywhere but couldn't find it. Please help.

Comment: Where were you searching? You should try searching on the internet: https://www.google.com/search?q="com.allen_sauer.gwt.dnd.demo.client.DemoDragHandler"

Comment: i already tried by downloading the jars gwt-dnd-3.0.1.jar,gwt-dnd-3.2.0.jar,gwt-dnd-3.1.1.jar,gwt-dnd-3.1.6.jar.but not a single one contains the class which i mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

That's a class part of the examples of [gwt-dnd](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/) library.

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/source/browse/DragDrop/demo/com/allen_sauer/gwt/dnd/demo/client/DemoDragHandler.java

You can download the full project code (include examples) from theirs git repository at googlecode: `git clone https://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/`.

Comment: thank you so much.is there any jar file for importing this class into my project so that i can use the features?

Comment: No, you have to copy those classes into your project, or create your own .jar (with eclipse is easy: File -> Export -> Java -> Jar File)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the API of that class you mentioned

[DemoDragHandler](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/allen-sauer/gwt/dnd/gwt-dnd/3.1.2/gwt-dnd-3.1.2-javadoc.jar!/com/allen_sauer/gwt/dnd/demo/client/DemoDragHandler.html)

[Class Heirarchy](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/allen-sauer/gwt/dnd/gwt-dnd/3.1.2/gwt-dnd-3.1.2-javadoc.jar!/com/allen_sauer/gwt/dnd/demo/client/package-tree.html?terms=com.allen_sauer.gwt.dnd.demo.client.DemoDragHandler)

[Whole jar package structure](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/inspect/com/allen-sauer/gwt/dnd/gwt-dnd/3.1.2/gwt-dnd-3.1.2-javadoc.jar)

[Download jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/allen-sauer/gwt/dnd/gwt-dnd/3.1.2/gwt-dnd-3.1.2-javadoc.jar)

BTW.. i found it through [Jarvana.com](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/)

Comment: In this jar is not the class file the user is asking for.

Comment: @Manolo oh..is it the same api which i mentioned and the OP asked  ??

Comment: the problem is that the user is asking for a file which is part of the library examples, so the class is not packaged with the library, but it is available in the project's SCM.

Comment: Oh..then i misunderstood...i can delete this answerbut ..let it be.OP may find some use.